# Increment value based on value in another column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table which contain the service_id,service_name,weight_start_range, Weight_end_range and increment_by.

```
service_id service_name weight_start_range  Weight_end_range    increment_by
sr1        Service1           0                    500             100
sr2        Service2           200                  300              0
sr3        Service3           0                    1000            500
sr4        Service4           0                    250              0
sr5        Service5           50                   100              0
```

I want to get data from this table and create one table as using SQL query:

```
service_id  service_name    weight_start_range  Weight_end_range 
sr1         Service1                0               100
sr1         Service1                100             200
sr1         Service1                200             300
sr1         Service1                300             400
sr1         Service1                400             500
sr2         Service2                200             300
sr3         Service3                0               500
sr3         Service3                500             1000
sr4         Service4                0               250
sr5         Service5                50              100
```

Can anyone help me in this?

I was unable to design table so attaching the image to see structure.[image]

Comment: Tip: while it is actually possible to do this in MySQL and I can imagine the way, but - do this with application. Read the table, generate SQL, based on that, then execute it and get result. Resolving this with SQL will serve only the goal to satisfy academical interest, but for production purposes - don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement first thought came into my mind was about writing a subqueries but providing looping functionality was a complex task there hence I decided to create procedure for it.

**DB setup :**

```
CREATE TABLE `servicedata` (
  `service_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `serviceName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight_start_range` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight_end_range` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `increment_by` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**SEED Data :**

```
insert into `servicedata` (`service_id`, `serviceName`, `weight_start_range`, `weight_end_range`, `increment_by`) values('sr1','srvice1','0','500','100');
insert into `servicedata` (`service_id`, `serviceName`, `weight_start_range`, `weight_end_range`, `increment_by`) values('sr2','service2','200','300','0');
insert into `servicedata` (`service_id`, `serviceName`, `weight_start_range`, `weight_end_range`, `increment_by`) values('sr3','service3','0','1000','500');
insert into `servicedata` (`service_id`, `serviceName`, `weight_start_range`, `weight_end_range`, `increment_by`) values('sr4','service4','0','250','0');
```

*servicedata table has following data :*

```
service_id  serviceName  weight_start_range  weight_end_range  increment_by
----------  -----------  ------------------  ----------------  ------------
sr1         srvice1                       0               500           100
sr2         service2                    200               300             0
sr3         service3                      0              1000           500
sr4         service4                      0               250             0
```

**PROCEDURE customOutPut :**

```
DELIMITER // 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS customOutPut//

CREATE PROCEDURE customOutPut()
BEGIN
DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE serviceid VARCHAR(50) ;
DECLARE servicename VARCHAR(50) ;
DECLARE START INTEGER ;
DECLARE END INTEGER ;
DECLARE incrementby INTEGER ;
DECLARE WEIGHT_END INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE endRange INTEGER;
DECLARE startRange INTEGER;

DECLARE selectCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT service_id,servicename , weight_START_range , weight_end_range ,increment_by 
    FROM servicedata; 

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DATA_SPREAD_WITH_INCREMENT_BY ;
CREATE TABLE DATA_SPREAD_WITH_INCREMENT_BY(service_id VARCHAR(50) ,servicename VARCHAR(50), weight_START_range INTEGER, weight_end_range INTEGER );

OPEN selectCursor;  

getData: LOOP

FETCH selectCursor INTO serviceid,servicename,START,END,incrementby ;

IF v_finished =1 THEN 
  LEAVE getData;
END IF ; 

IF incrementby = 0 THEN
   INSERT INTO DATA_SPREAD_WITH_INCREMENT_BY VALUES (serviceid,servicename,START,END);

ELSE 
 SET endRange =START;
 SET startRange = START;
    spreadData: LOOP

    SET endRange = endRange+incrementby ;
    IF endrange > END THEN
        LEAVE spreadData;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO DATA_SPREAD_WITH_INCREMENT_BY VALUES (serviceid,servicename,startRange,endRange);

    SET startRange = startRange+incrementby ;

    END LOOP;  

END IF ;    

END LOOP getData;

END  //
DELIMITER ;
```

You should call the procedure as  `CALL customOutPut()`

to see data as available in data_spread_with_increment_by fire below SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `data_spread_with_increment_by`
```

**Table data_spread_with_increment_by**

```
service_id  servicename  weight_START_range  weight_end_range
----------  -----------  ------------------  ----------------
sr1         (NULL)                        0               100
sr1         (NULL)                      100               200
sr1         (NULL)                      200               300
sr1         (NULL)                      300               400
sr1         (NULL)                      400               500
sr2         (NULL)                      200               300
sr3         (NULL)                        0               500
sr3         (NULL)                      500              1000
sr4         (NULL)                        0               250
```

I have provided this procedure as an guidance and I might have missed some edge cases but I am sure you can certainly figure them out.

Please post your suggestion whether this procedure works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks Shree. I tried with procedure and it is working fine but can we do it in sql only.